# Добавление tor и privoxy в автозагрузку (Kali)

Tags: linux, администрирование

Никак не получается добавить их в автозагрузку. Система стоит на Oracle VirtualBox
делал все по инструкции по данной [ccылке](https://codeby.net/bezopasnost/kak-ves-trafik-v-kali-linux-propuskat-cherez-tor-nastrojka-tor-i-privoxy-v-kali-linux-2-0/)

Если после загрузки системы написать

```
curl ident.me
```

то в ответ вываливается кусок html кода от какой-то то ли справки по privoxy то ли еще чего.

Особенность заключается в том, что до этого систему разворачивал с готового образа для oracle virtual box и проблем не возникло, по точно такой же инструкции все делал и все было в порядке (автозагрузка работала). В этот же раз ставил так же на virtual box систему, НО с чистого iso устанавливал. Подскажите в чем может быть беда?

При этом после ручного запуска

```
Service tor start
Service privoxy start
```

Все работает как положено.

Comment: А как вообще тор и привокси устанавливались?

Comment: @donRumata в тексте ссылка. Вообще по классике apt-get наше все.

Comment: Ну там есть строка `update-rc.d -f tor remove && update-rc.d -f tor defaults && update-rc.d -f privoxy remove && update-rc.d -f privoxy defaults && update-rc.d -f privoxy enable`. Ты её делал?

Comment: @donRumata естественно, я же написал что я сделал все по данной ссылке, команда исполнилась, ошибок не выдала, перезагружаюсь, результата ноль.

Comment: А если поставить пакет `rcconf` и через него попробовать?

Comment: И ещё: ты ставил самую последнюю версию с https://www.kali.org/downloads/?

Comment: @donRumata извиняюсь за задержку ответа. Да ставил именно оттуда, последнюю 64-битную версию. В понедельник попробую rcconf, тк дома стоит развернутая из  ova образа. А вот на работе (где проблемы с добавлением в автозагрузку) разворачивал с iso как раз, вообще пробовал еще и через sysv-rc-conf добавлять, но то ли я что то не так делаю, то ли действительно что-то неведомое происходит.